# How to prevent a page from refreshing when I want to submit a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, django-forms

I am trying to build my first website and I encountered a problem that I couldn't resolve by now. So, when an user wants to add an item to the cart, or to increment the quantity, I want to prevent the page from refreshing when hitting the submit button. I've looked for many answers, I tried to apply Ajax/JQuery, but unsuccessful.

Here is my code:

html

```
<form action="{% url 'cart-add' %}" method="GET" id="myform">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <label>
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ product.pk }}">
        <input type="number" max="{{ product.quantity }}" min="1" name="quantity" value="1">
        <button type="submit" value="">Add to chart</button>
    </label>
</form>
```

Ajax/JQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "GET",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("myForm").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When I hit add-to-cart submit button, it throw me to the "cart.html". I do not want to do that, instead I want to prevent that and throw a message to the user saying that his/her item has been successfully added.

Can somebody help me? Thank you very much for your time. I much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Is `$('myform')` a typo? Should it be `$('#myform')`?

- To reference a HTML's ID, use a `#idName`.
- To reference a HTML class, use a `.className`
- To reference a HTML element, just enter `name`

`$('myform')` is looking for a `<myform></myform>` element.

`$('#myform')` is looking for a `<... id="myform"></...>`

`$('.myform')` is looking for a `<... class="myform anotherRandomClass"></...>`

Comment: It is the id of my form. id="myform". Shall I rename it?

Comment: No, the id is fine, just when you're trying to access it, you need to use a `#` so jQuery knows it's an id!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return false`, otherwise, the function with carry on with the default behaviour after the function is complete:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) { // fix typo
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "GET",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("myForm").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
        // Prevent function from saving
         return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Update: looking at the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/submit/#submit-handler), I don't know if `return false` is necessary if `e.preventDefault()` is present.

Comment: I have included return false; in my code, but it still does the same thing. When I hit the submit button, it throw me to the cart.html. I think I am doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting normally because your jquery selector is wrong. You have to change `$('myform')` to `$('#myform')`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : $(this).attr('action') || window.location.pathname,
            type: "GET",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $("#myform").html(data);
            },
            error: function (jXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I update it and is still sending me on another page...

Comment: It is still not working, When i click view page source, the script isn't even displayed in the broweser. Perhaps this is the issue. I edit my code according to yours and it's still not working. As soon as I hit the submit button, it throw me on cart page.

Comment: Make sure you have included jQuery before the submit script on the page.